# String not printing out in loop due to incorrect length

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with string length.  I do not understand at all why my str3 has a length of 0.  Why does it have a 0 length? I initialize it with 0, but later on in a for loop I give each index of the str3 a value of _.  I assume that each of those underscores gives the str3 another index, which means the length will increase one, right?  What's going on?

What the program is doing is finding certain index values in two string comparisons(str1 and str2) and giving str3 the index values that correspond with 0(from the output of tempvar)

```
for (int z = 0; z < str1.length(); z++){
                //str3 initilization
                str3[z] = '_';
                std::cout << str3[z];

                    if(z == str1.length() - 1){
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
            }
```

This is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    std::string str1;
    std::string str2 = "RLSTNE";
    std::string str3;
    std::string* arr_temp =  new std::string[10];
    std::string* arr_temp1 = new std::string[10];

    bool restart = true;

    do{

        std::cout << "What string?" << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, str1);

        *arr_temp1 = str1;
        *arr_temp = str2;

        for (int z = 0; z < str1.length(); z++){
            //str3 initilization
            str3[z] = '_';
            std::cout << str3[z];

                if(z == str1.length() - 1){
                    std::cout << std::endl;
                }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < str2.length(); y++)
        {//index replacement
            for(int x = 0;x <= str1.length(); x++)
            {       
                int tempvar = arr_temp->compare(y,1, *arr_temp1, x, 1);

                    if((tempvar == 0))
                        { 
                            str3[x] = str1[x];
                        }
            }   
        }   

std::cout << "Restart? 1 = yes, 0 = no" << std::endl;
std::cin >> restart;

    }while(restart);

     std::cout << "str3: ";
     for(int xy = 0; xy < str3.length(); xy++)
     {//str3 print
        std::cout << str3[xy];
     }   

        if(restart == false)
        {
            delete arr_temp;
            delete arr_temp1;
            arr_temp = NULL;
            arr_temp1 = NULL;
            std::cout << *arr_temp1 <<std::endl;
        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is too much code for this problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but my guess is that you're neglecting the null-termination.

Comment: What is that `std::string* arr_temp =  new std::string[10];`. Makes no sense what so ever. The deletes are mismatched and should not be conditional, and what is this: `std::cout << *arr_temp1 <<std::endl;`???

Comment: And of course it has a size of 0, you never allocate space int he string, but you do access inexistent memory in it. That's bad on so many levels...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I deleted the string arrays.  I'll just use regular strings.  The line in the conditional delete statement is to test if my pointer is deleted.  How do I allocate space inside of the string?  Without making it a char array?  I create indexes to the string when I initialize them with the underscores

Comment: If you allocate an array, you have to deallocate an array. Your `delete` should be `delete[]` And dereferencing a `NULL` pointer in `cout` (or anywhere else) is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: How come, what can happen? @Yksisarvinen

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen, including [demons flying out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Most commonly, segmentation fault occurs (ie. your operating system stops the program to prevent it from messing up memory it doesn't have access to).

Answer (score 4):

str3 is an empty string and when you run:

```
str3[z] = '_';
std::cout << str3[z];
```

You are accessing an invalid index, as the string is empty.

So, you first should set str3 size, before the loop:

```
str3.resize(str1.length());
```

If are not clear to you the std::string behavior, instead of using [] operator, you can try to use the at member function for accessing individual characters, as if the index is invalid, it will throw an exception:

```
std::string any;
any.at(5) = 'a'; //will throw std::out_of_range
```

Comment: It may be worth adding something about how using `.at()` over the subscript operator would've caught this and left no ambiguity to what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Your `str3` is empty because you didn't specify a length when creating it, i.e. it has a size of 0. Accessing/modifying elements with `[]` with indices beyond size is undefined (for [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)).

You should initialize `str3` with a fill constructor (the [second one in the list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)), or use `resize` on it before accessing and modifying elements of it.